# Sign out from Windows Authenticated ADFS and sign in as different user in form base auth

Tags: asp.net, authentication, windows-authentication, adfs

We are going enhance the authentication and authorization system of our Intranet web app. After having few days reading about ADFS, STS, claim based authentication, asp.net Identity. Still not sure how these things works together.

Most of our intranet web applications are using Windows Integrated Authentication, we uses windows group or AzMan to do role base authorization. We have few applications(Vendor application) use it own user database and form base authentication.

We want to add following features to our web applications.

1. For Windows Authentication application, we want to let user to Sign Out / Sign in as different user. So when User A using his/her computer to access the application, it will auto logged in (default windows integrated authentication). When he/she do log out, it will redirect to a form to allow to input other user credential.
2. We want to allow user login to System A using System B username/password.
   e.g. For the windows authentication application, we want allow user login to the application using the credential of the Form base application (Vendor application) of via visa

I don't know if ADFS can solve these two problems.

From my understanding, the main purpose of ADFS is to allow access to internal application from Internet, and it require SSL.

Our application all are in Intranet, and we don't want to manage the ssl cert.

But by using ADFS, perhaps I can enable both Windows and Form Authentication on my application, so then let use log out and re-direct him to the login form as which just like he access outside company network. It should solve the problem 1.

For problem 2, what if I can create a custom STS to issue security token by using the user database of the form base authentication appliaction. Then I can use claim based authentication and allow one application can use ADFS and my STS. It should solve my problem 2.

Is my direction correct? or am I complicated the problem?

Answer (score 0):

ADFS will not work without SSL.

Furthermore, all RP have to use SSL.

Internally, users will be logged in seamlessly using WIA. When they logout, they will simply be seamlessly logged in again.

Also ADFS v3.0 and below can only authenticate against AD.

Answer (score 0):

While what you want is possible using ADFS, the question is whether it's a good idea and worth the trouble. It may be more appropriate to ask the user to log out of the machine and log in with a different account so you can stick with Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA). Writing your own security infrastructure is fraught with peril.

If you really feel these are hard requirements and it is worth the trouble, the following may work.

Write an ASP.NET web application based on Katana and [enable Integrated Windows Authentication](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/enabling-windows-authentication-in-katana). This will make sure that the first time a completely unauthenticated request comes in, the application will challenge the browser. Subsequent requests will have a WindowsPrincipal populated in the `HttpContext.User` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.

Now, write a piece of [OWIN middleware](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/11/11/writing-owin-middleware.aspx) that checks if an authentication cookie is present. If the cookie is not present, it checks the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and serializes the claims into a secure cookie.

If the security cookie is present, it overwrites the `WindowsPrincipal` in `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` with a new `ClaimsPrincipal` created from the claims in the cookie.

Now, when a user navigates to the web application the first time, he/she will be logged in automatically using IWA and the cookie will be created. Now, provide a logout action which deletes the authentication cookie and presents the user with a username and password dialog.

In the POST handler for that action, use WIF to [talk to the username endpoint](http://leandrob.com/2012/04/requesting-a-token-from-adfs-2-0-using-ws-trust-with-username-and-password/) in ADFS (using WS-Trust protocol) and try to authenticate the user with the supplied credentials. If successful, use the claims from the returned token to create a new authentication cookie.